# Saving Date and Time from Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Rails novice here, please forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

I have a model called `Game` which has a `datetime` column in its table called `occurred_at`. As you might guess, information is meant to store the date/time at which a `game` occurred. So far, in creating my `game` objects, I have used `seeds.rb` to populate the `occurred_at` attribute by calling, `Time.parse(str)`. (e.g. `Time.parse("1 February 2017 5:00 PM PST")`)

Now I'm working on the `_form` for the `games#new` and `games#edit` pages. This is (very basically) what I'd like the `_form` to look like:

```
<%= form_for @game do |f| %>
  <%= f.date_field :date %>
  <%= f.time_field :time %>
  <%= f.text_field :home_team %>
  <%= f.text_field :away_team %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously, this won't work. `@game` doesn't have `date` and `time` methods. The date and time of `@game` are accessed via `@game.occurred_at`. The intuitive solution is to pass `date` and `time` in my params and then add logic in my `GamesController` to create/update `@game.occurred_at` accordingly.

So I have three inquiries:

1. Do I have the right idea as to the underlying solution of passing `date` and `time` parameters and combining them in `GamesController`? If not, what is the best way to accomplish the objective of updated `:occurred_at`?
2. If my idea as to the underlying solution is correct, how would I go about implementing that in my application?
3. Usually when an object is created or updated, the `params` are passed in the controller directly to the method responsible for the creation or update of the object. Does this affect my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple choice to do this.

1/ Your answer could work, but you need to declare :date and :time as attributes accessor for it to work and the add the logic in your controller to combine the passed arguments into :occured_at

2/ You can use rails datetime_select http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select

3/ Bit more complicated is to create all form input of the datetime object, but I am not sure this is the best solution.

EDIT:
For your answer to work, you need to edit your model like this

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :date, :time

  ... rest of your code
end
```

Then in the method of your controller:

```
game = params[:game]
date = game[:date]
time = game[:time]
occured_at = Time.parse "#{date} #{time}"
@game = Game.new(game)
@game.occured_at = occured_at
@game.save!
```

There is faster way to code this, but I purposely put each line for you to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Jay, Could you try the answer? I hope it is working for you. If yes, could you mark the answer as accepted?